# Why doesn't the Select statement assigns an empty string or null value if it doesn't return a result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
declare @testValue nvarchar(50) = 'TEST';

select @testValue = 'NOTUSED' where 1 > 2;
select @testValue; -- Outputs 'TEST'
select @testValue = 'USED' where 2 > 1;
select @testValue; -- Outputs 'USED'
```

With the above, the first assignment is never used because the where clause fails. The second one is done properly and used is returned.

Why doesn't SQL return a null in this case and assigns a NULL value to @testValue after the first assignment where the where clause fails?

Comment: Are those > signs oriented right?  where 2 > 1 is true, right?

Comment: also value looks like it should be testValue

Comment: Hmm. You're correct. I got it backwards.. The first select statement when run will return an empty result set. But @testValue is never set to NULL or an empty string in this case. It still retains the value of 'TEST'. I'm curious as to why this is happening and if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior:

"If the SELECT statement returns no rows, the variable retains its present value. If expression is a scalar subquery that returns no value, the variable is set to NULL."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx

You can get around this in your example by using a subquery in the right side.

```
SELECT @testValue = (SELECT 'NOTUSED' where 1 > 2);
```

As for why it is this way, I cannot say for certain.  Perhaps the entire `@testValue = 'NOTUSED'` is equating to NULL instead of only the right side `'NOTUSED'` portion of the statement, and this prevents the parameter from being set.  Not directly related but I can say it took me some time to grow confident with writing queries when NULLs are involved.  You need to be aware of / familiar with the ANSI NULL spec and associated behavior.

Comment: This might be clearer if you did it as `SET @testValue = (SELECT ...)`.

Comment: Understood and agree, but I do want to show that the subquery alone is sufficient to get the desired effect, as this may provide some insight as to why the engine behaves the way it does.

Comment: I think SET does exactly that. It's all about the difference between rowsets and values (and expressions). SELECT is intended for rowsets. In a query assigning a variable, no rows means no assignment. But when SELECT is overloaded to assign a *value* then "no rows AS value" as NULL. It's the parentheses that work the magic. Try parentheses with two columns or with a query that returns more than 1 row...

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of `SELECT`.

When assigning a value to a variable using `SELECT`, if there is no value returned, `SELECT` will not make the assignment at all so the variable's value will not be changed.

On the other hand, `SET` will assign `NULL` to the variable if there is no value returned.

[For more info](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/differences_between_set_and_select.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is the ideal value you would like but the SQL engine is not clever enough, because some else may want empty string , ' ' in that situation or 0 or 1, you see. So no single default value  is set. Best is set your own default value. You can see below

```
DECLARE @testValue NVARCHAR(50) = 'TEST';

SELECT @testValue = 'NOTUSED' WHERE 2 > 1;

IF 2 <> 1
  SELECT @testValue = NULL;

SELECT @testValue; -- Outputs 'TEST'
SELECT @testValue = 'USED' WHERE 1 > 2;
SELECT @testValue; -- Outputs 'USED'
```

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` in SQL is used to denote missing data or an unknown value. In this case the data is not missing, the value of @testValue is known, it is just failing an assignment condition, so it gets no new value.

If you were to change your initial assignment to be like this

```
declare @testValue nvarchar(50)
```

You would get NULL like below :

```
select @testValue = 'NOTUSED' where 1 > 2;
select @testValue; -- Outputs NULL
select @testValue = 'USED' where 2 > 1;
select @testValue; -- Outputs 'USED'
```

Don't be too disappointed your not getting `NULL` back in the your example. `NULL` is not easy to handle.

For example, you can not compare two `NULL` values, because instances of `NULL` are not equal. Consequently you also need to use special operators like `ISNULL` to check for it.

In general, `NULL` as a programming construct should be avoided in my opinion. This is a bit of area of contention across the programming languages. But consdier this, even the creator of null [Tony Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare), calls the creation of null his 'billion dollar mistake'.